# writting a code for finding the Kostant partition function

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory, lie-algebras

How to write a code in sage for finding the Kostant partition function for the elements of root lattice of rank 1 affine lie algebra $A_{1}^{(1)}$ which is defined as follows:
$K(\beta)$ = the co-efficient of $e^{\beta}$ in $\prod _{\alpha \in \bigtriangleup}(1-e^{\alpha})$ where $\bigtriangleup$ is the set of positive roots of $A_{1}^{(1)}$ and $\beta$ is an element of the root lattice ?

Comment: It would maybe help if you reminded what that set of positive roots is, and what the dimension of the space is in which they live. My vague recollection is that they look something like $\{\,(a,b)\in\mathbf Z^2\mid a+b=1\,\}$; however that would be disturbing since the infinite product would not converge in the formal power series ring (one gets infinitely many partitions, even just for $(1,1)$).

Comment: Here set of positive roots are $\{(n-1)\alpha_0 + n \alpha_1,(n-1)\alpha_1 + n \alpha_0,n \alpha_0 + n \alpha_1: n \geq 1\}$,where $\alpha_0$ and $\alpha_1$ are two simple roots of $A_{1}^{(1)}$.If $\beta = k_{0} \alpha_0 + k_{1} \alpha_{1}$ where $k_1,k_2 \in Z$ i want to find  $K(\beta)$.

Comment: This smells of the [Jacobi triple product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product) (which I don't claim to understand very well). Indeed the link provided suggests it is close. But I really can't help beyond this.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful dear senior :
https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~deloera/kostant.html